# MySQL SELECT MAX, other fields have wrong values

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query which uses the MAX function to select max session_date field:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date), value 
FROM user_extra 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Problem with it is that the value field doesn't seem to be accurate, it seems to get the wrong value data from one of the other date entries. Any ideas why this is and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's GROUP BY is a bit peculiar.

Your query will return MAX(session_date) for each user_id group. However, nothing specifies which value will be returned: you will get a random value for each user_id group.

If you would like the value for the line which has the maximum session_date for each user_id, you will need another query, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date) AS session_date
FROM user_extra GROUP BY user_id) AS foo 
JOIN user_extra USING (user_id,session_date)
```

Comment: What about value?

Comment: I dont think so.* will Fetch the data from table foo which doesn't contain value.

Comment: I know. I think OP is capable of putting the columns he wants into the select list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(session_date) as date_session, value FROM user_extra GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: other than the as date_session, I dont see what is different with your code. Still does the same thing